# Localhost wont render properly but github pages will?

Tags: reactjs

My create-react-app was loading perfectly fine on my localhost however after running npm start on a few different occasions and re-opening the browser (accidentally closed a few times no code changes), the application stopped loading properly. It was working fine and changes in the code were not made to cause it to break.

My application is also deployed on github pages and renders perfectly on that although localhost wont load correctly. Does anyone have any advice for what may be causing this?

Comment: Could you please at least provide some code sample?

Comment: It could be any number of things. Is the server running? Are you navigating to the correct address (port, path, etc.)? Is there a stale storage value that is preventing render (local storage, cookies, service worker, etc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/17f2A.png)? It's difficult to provide help without reproduction steps. Try again in a private browsing session.

Comment: Apologies for not posting a code snippet initially as I was not sure of the relevant code to post. The issue with the local host also seems to be that the styling isn't applied. 

After messing with the code some more I realized the page renders correctly by adding a '/' after the URL or by clicking any of the href's on the initial render. Is there a way for the localhost to automatically load as:

"http://localhost:3005/business-page-template /"

instead of

http://localhost:3005/business-page-template"